# How can I carry out multiple different animations at different times with the same UIButton?

Tags: swift, xcode, animation, uibutton

I am creating an animation sequence where when one button is pressed one object fades out. When the same button is pressed again another object fades out. This keeps happening until 8 objects are faded out. I have tried and played around with code and so far have got the code to fade out one object, and two or more at a time, but have not successfully been able to do it as described above. This is my code so far:

```
import UIKit

class DrinkWaterViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var glassOne: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var glassTwo: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var glassThree: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var glassFour: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var glassFive: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var glassSix: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var glassSeven: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var glassEight: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.glassOne.alpha = 1.0
        self.glassTwo.alpha = 1.0
    }

    @IBAction func drunkOne(_ sender: Any){

        if self.glassOne.alpha == 1.0{

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, delay: 0.2, animations:
            {self.glassOne.alpha = CGFloat(0.1)}
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your glasses into an array `glasses` and add a property to keep track of `nextToFade`.  Then just fade the `glasses[nextToFade]` and increment `nextToFade` by `1`:

```
class DrinkWaterViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var glassOne: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var glassTwo: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var glassThree: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var glassFour: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var glassFive: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var glassSix: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var glassSeven: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var glassEight: UIImageView!

    // array to hold the glasses so that they can be indexed
    var glasses = [UIImageView]()

    // index of next glass to fade
    var nextToFade = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // put the glasses into the array
        glasses = [glassOne, glassTwo, glassThree, glassFour,
                    glassFive, glassSix, glassSeven, glassEight]

        // make sure they're all visible
        glasses.forEach { $0.alpha = 1.0 }
    }

    @IBAction func drunkOne(_ sender: Any) {
        // make sure not to index beyond the end of the array
        guard nextToFade < glasses.count else { return }

        let glass = glasses[nextToFade]
        nextToFade += 1
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, delay: 0.2, animations:
            { glass.alpha = 0.1 }
        )
    }
}
```